# Trying to get the value of a specific column in every row of a dataset in visual c#

Tags: c#, oracle, dataset, datarow

Sorry if the title is confusing.  I was trying to keep it short.

I have a DataSet *ds*.  In this dataSet are seven columns, One Machine Schedule Order, Two Machine Schedule Order, Series, Oven, Battery, and Oven Control Number.

I want to do a for loop from 1 to 183 (which is how many records there are, and they're the values of One Machine Schedule Order, which is a primary key), finding what the values of series, oven, and battery are in the matching row.

If I were to mix C# and SQL, what I would do is:

```
for (int i = 1; i<184; i++)
{
    String result = SELECT series||battery||'/'||oven where \"One Machine Schedule Order\" = i
    Console.WriteLine(result)
}
```

So if that doesn't make sense, I want to get one value back per row and I want it stored in a string.  Then I want to output that string to the screen.

`DataRow[] row = ds.Tables[0].Select("'One Machine Schedule Order' = " + "'"+i+"'");`

Above is how I'm getting each row, and then just to see if the data was getting there, I tried
`Console.WriteLine(row[0][0]);` to print the value of the first column, which should be a three digit number.  However, I'm getting an `IndexOutOfRangeException` on that statement.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Console.WriteLine(row[0].ItemArray[0])
```

Comment: Hmm, still throwing the exception.  I decided to catch the exception and write the source and it's just giving me the namespace as the source

Comment: then may  be  datarow is null   because the select return  null review the select debug code  and  but  breakpoint    and  use watch window to check if  datarow has data

Answer (score 0):

Try this.This should work if I understand your question right

```
foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dr[0].ToString());
        }
```